# special charcter with url

Tags: php, url-rewriting, character-encoding

i 've using a htmlentities for removing special character in request url but is not work.
the code correspond to call my url is:

```
 <select name="article">
 <option value='Tout' >Tout</option>  
 echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($rowact['article']).'" ';
if(...))
{
{echo 'selected';} 
}
echo'>'.htmlentities($rowact['article']).' </option>';
```

url: http://mondomain.com/+Bar%252C+caf%25C3%25A9%2

Any suggestion please, thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode -- http://php.net/urldecode  see if this helps, read the comments for additional help

Answer (score 1):

htmlentities is not for encoding urls
use [urlencode](http://de3.php.net/urlencode) to encode special characters in urls

Answer (score 0):

using htmlentities you can convert html entities but to encode url parameters you must have to use urlencode function.

`

Tout  
 echo ''.htmlentities($rowact['article']).' ';   `

[urlencode description](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

Comment: thx but not works , this instruction convert dropdown list not the value passed in url

Comment: by which method you are going to pass values in url?

Comment: can you share your url or code with me? I will fix that for you.

Comment: I mentioned the url and the corresponding code in the question

Answer (score 0):

htmlentities convert all applicable characters to HTML entities (see http://www.php.net/htmlentities).
If you want to allow only certain characters, use a regular expression such as this:

```
preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]*)/","",$rowact['activite'])
```

This example allows only letters (upper and lower case), numbers and spaces.
For more informations check here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Edit:

Even if it's not the best possible solution, you could replace specific special characters using preg_replace, as in the following code:

```
$find = array();
$find[] = '/[\"]/';
$find[] = '/[\&]/';
$find[] = '/[\<]/';
$find[] = '/[\>]/';

$replace = array();
$replace[] = "&quot;";
$replace[] = "&amp;";
$replace[] = "&lt;";
$replace[] = "&gt;";

preg_replace($find,$replace,$rowact['activite']);
```